# Popup dialog with transparent background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to create popup dialog with Jetpack Compose which could be declared as NavHost destination route and called from any other app page.

An example of desired result:

[image]

Compose framework provides Dialog component, but it's hard to customize and there is ugly built-in animation. I would prefer to build my own fully customizable popup view with optional custom animation. The problem - I can't create popup with transparent sideview, it's black.

Any ideas?

**UPD:**

A little more code to make it clear

```
override fun onCreate(savedState: Bundle?) {
    NavHost(navController = controller, startDestination = "main_page") {
        composable(route = "main_page", content = { MainPage() })
        composable(route = "my_popup", content = { ThePopupDialog() })
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainPage() {
    // ... some button here to launch "my_popup" route by click
}

@Composable
fun ThePopupDialog() {
    Box {
        Text("The popup content here")
    }
}
```

Box view in ThePopupDialog doesn't cover the whole screen and I need the sidearea to be (half)transparent.

Comment: What code have you tried already? The deepest solution is to study the source code of `Dialog`, and create your own analog of [`DialogWrapper`](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/022470f13e1bd1aac107e2aa7e044f0bb1ca6e09/compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/AndroidDialog.android.kt#L258).

Comment: Unfortunately, my project code is under NDA and can't be posted here. But I tried to use existing Dialog component with no success (because it doesn't provide customization handles). Tried to use regular @Composable views, but was not able to make them transparent.

Comment: I'm definitely not asking for the code of your project. Show me the code where you failed to make the view transparent.

Comment: I know this project is under NDA, but stack-overflow also have a terms and rules and you must understand it. so you can't write a problem without any code, we're just asking for `Dialog` code (not all project code), you can create a new project and write your dialog codes, then if it still not working you should share it here

Comment: @a7d.24_ there is high-level code to illustrate the desired result. Do you have anything to advise?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Yes, the hardest way to clone DialogWrapper functionality. But I believe there should be simple and flexible solution provided by the framework.

Comment: @SergeyKrivenkov It's not gonna work with compose navigation for sure: prev destination is disappearing from the view tree after the transition animation. Why don't you add it on top of your view using `Box`?

Answer (score -9):

You can simply create a custom dialogue class as follows:
First you need to create a layout in app/res/layout/new.xml according to your choice, in my case it was:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:background="#3E80B4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="COMING SOON !"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#3E80B4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textColor="#5DBCD2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then create a new java class in app/java/com.example.yourappname and write the following code:

```java
package com.example.yourappname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class OkDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    public Button yes;

    public OkDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.c = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.ok_dialog);
        yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
        yes.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_yes:
                dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

and use it in your activity as follows:

```java
OkDialog myDialogue = new OkDialog(MainActivity.this);
myDialogue.show();
```